# Neo4j - Model nodes and relationship

Tags: neo4j, model, cypher

I got 100000 employee data in the format {company:[c1,c2,c3],designation:[d1,d2,d3]} where c1 is employee's 1st company, c2 is 2nd company and c3 3rd ...
Same applies for the designations the employee had at those companies respectively.
Here a switch means when an employee switched from c1->c2 or d1->d2.

I wish to model this in neo4j to answer the following questions:

1. Get company switches for eg. c1->c2, c2->c3
2. Get designation switches for eg. d1->d2, d2->d3.
3. For a company switch c1->c2 what are designation switches d1->d2.

I tried this code but it keeps on running forever even when i already indexed.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.id IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Company) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:Designation) ASSERT d.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE INDEX ON :Company(type),

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/positions.csv" AS row
WITH row

// user
MERGE (u:User {id: row.user})
ON CREATE SET u.id = row.user
//comp
MERGE (n:Company {name:row.name})
ON CREATE SET n.name = row.name, n.type = row.type



// ---------------------------  Approach 2
CREATE (p:Position{user: row.user, duration: toFloat(row.duration),     sequence:toInt(row.sequence)})
CREATE (p)-[:AT]->(n)
// optionally build Designation
FOREACH(c1 IN (CASE WHEN row.type = 'c' THEN [1] else [] END) |
// maybe check for empty
//title
MERGE (d:Designation {title:row.title})
ON CREATE SET d.title = row.title
CREATE (p)-[:AS]->(d)
)
WITH row 

MATCH (u:User{id:row.user})
MATCH (p:Position{user: u.id, sequence:0})
CREATE (u)-[:NEXT]->(p)
WITH row, p
// todo - link sequence 0 position
MATCH (p:Position {user: row.user})
WITH p ORDER BY p.sequence
WITH COLLECT(p) AS positions
FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, length(positions)-2) | 
FOREACH(pos1 in [positions[i]] | 
    FOREACH(pos2 in [positions[i+1]] | 
      CREATE UNIQUE (pos1)-[:NEXT]->(pos2))))
```

Here sequence is the sequence of the Postion held by the user/employee

Comment: Your question's terminology is so obscure that it is likely to be closed. For instance, what do you mean by "designation" and "switches"? Please explain your use case and your data model in enough detail for others to understand. Also, if you have existing Cypher code, show that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, edited with relavant terminlogies.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to model your data? If so, please share them, and the challenges you're encountering. If you haven't, then please share any thoughts you've had about the approaches you're considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to model your data, along with the queries for your use cases.

This sample data model uses a "chain" of `Job` nodes separated by `HISTORY` relationships to record the job history of an employee. The most recent job is directly attached to the employee (also by a `HISTORY` relationship). Each `Job` node has one relationship to a `Company` node and another to a `Designation` node.

#### Create sample data

```
CREATE
  (c1:Company {id: 123, name: 'Acme Corp.'}),
  (c2:Company {id: 321, name: 'Bank of Peoria'}),
  (c3:Company {id: 444, name: 'Consolidated Cans'}),
  (d1:Designation {id: 234, title: 'Assistant Clerk'}),
  (d2:Designation {id: 345, title: 'Clerk'}),
  (d3:Designation {id: 456, title: 'Head Clerk'}),
  (e1:Employee {id: 123456789, name: 'Fred Murphy'}),

  (c1)<-[:AT]-(j1:Job {started: 123456789})-[:AS]->(d1),
  (c2)<-[:AT]-(j2:Job {started: 234567890})-[:AS]->(d2),
  (c3)<-[:AT]-(j3:Job {started: 345678901})-[:AS]->(d3),

  (e1)-[:HISTORY]->(j3)-[:HISTORY]->(j2)-[:HISTORY]->(j1);
```

#### Get company changes (with start dates):

```
MATCH p=(n)<-[:HISTORY*]-(e1:Employee {id: 123456789})
WHERE NOT ()<-[:HISTORY]-(n)
WITH NODES(p)[0..-1] AS jobs
UNWIND jobs AS job
MATCH (job)-[:AT]->(c)
RETURN c, job.started;
```

#### Get designation changes (with start dates):

```
MATCH p=(n)<-[:HISTORY*]-(e1:Employee {id: 123456789})
WHERE NOT ()<-[:HISTORY]-(n)
WITH NODES(p)[0..-1] AS jobs
UNWIND jobs AS job
MATCH (job)-[:AS]->(d)
RETURN d, job.started;
```

#### Get matching company/designation changes (with start dates):

```
MATCH p=(n)<-[:HISTORY*]-(e1:Employee {id: 123456789})
WHERE NOT ()<-[:HISTORY]-(n)
WITH NODES(p)[0..-1] AS jobs
UNWIND jobs AS job
MATCH (c)<-[:AT]-(job)-[:AS]->(d)
RETURN c, d, job.started;
```